# 4 bits logic unit

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I understand how 1 bit logic work . For example A =0 and B=1  => A and B = 0 //
 A or B = 1 .

But how do you work out if A and B are 4 bits . For example A[0,0,1,1] and B[0,0,0,1]
What are A and B , A or B in 4 bits ? How do I work them out.

Comment: Same principle. In your example: A[0] * B[0] = C[0]; A[1] * B[1] = C[1] etc.. So, 1*1 = 1, 0*1=0 etc.. Therefore, result of AND is 0001; Result of OR is 0011.

Answer (score 1):

While @Alper91 makes the point correctly, I'll expand.

An ALU does logic operations on a bit-by-bit basis. It does not do logic operations on the entirety of a field. So, 0110 anded with 1100 is 0100. There is no attempt to determine, for instance, if the 4 bits in either field produce a single bit which represents all 4 bits anded together.